# Android application error

Tags: android

i developed application with map service and webservices when i run application its became very slow and continuosly it is showing activity not responding force close or wait

how to resolve this issue

Thanks in advance

Aswan

Comment: What kind of web service are using? Maybe the connection is slow or you are requesting to much data. Please provide more details about your problem.

Comment: i am using server side .net client side ksoap2 getting people details and displying on map

Comment: Do you run the "slow" code into a separated thread?

Comment: by getting data from webservice i wrote that code inside scheduleAtFixedRate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider use the AsyncTask to run web service in the background. Feedback to UI when data fetched completely.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html